# What is the best way to update the match formula to conditionally format?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, formulas

=MATCH(C$13, 'Vacation - Holiday'!$B:$B, 0)

C13 is the date 01/01/2016.

I am using this formula to conditionally format a cell in a calendar dashboard.   It works great but I need the lookup array to be dependent on the name listed in cell B15.

Can I use AND(Match())?  I have tried many things and feel so close but so far.

"Meg" is the header of the "B" column on sheet 'Vacation - Holiday'!$B:$B.  There are names in columns A - J.

```
A     B           C           D        E            F         G           H
              1/1/2016   1/4/2016   1/5/2016    1/6/2016    1/7/2016    1/8/2016
     Meg
```

Comment: What's the condition to format? Whenever "meg" is in col. b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you want is:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(C$13,INDEX(Sheet6!$A:$J,0,MATCH($B15,Sheet6!$1:$1,0)),0))
```

Comment: Vacation Holiday sheet has Meg as the header for column B.  If the date in row 13 is in column I would like to highlight that date on the dashboard where that persons name and that date intersect.

Comment: I need to find the column based on the header row then search that column for the date.  =MATCH(C$13, 'Vacation - Holiday'!$B:$B, 0)This formula works but is not dependent on the cell listed in B15.  I need to update to search Vacation - Holiday'!$1:$1 for the nam elisted in B15 then search that column for the date in row 13.